# Where do the Locator methods go when using a ServiceLocator?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, service-locator

If I use separate service classes with a `ServiceLocator`, do I still need to define the `Locator` methods somewhere?:

```
T create(Class<? extends T> clazz)
I getId(T domainObject)
T find(Class<? extends T> clazz, I id)
Object getVersion(T domainObject)
```

Do they go on the service class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, these two types serve orthogonal purposes: A `ServiceLocator` finds code;  a `Locator` finds entities.

Using a `ServiceLocator` does not change where the entity support methods are declared.  The entity support methods are still searched for in the domain types.

Comment: Still confused. I went down the ServiceLocator route because I need to inject (via Guice) a MongoDB reference for use by my persistence code. But I still need to define entity support methods on the domain types? How then shall those entity support methods make use of my MongoDB?

Comment: You will wind up using both a `Locator` for injecting your domain entity types and handling the getId()/getVersion() methods and a `ServiceLocator` for configuring your service objects.

Comment: Found a [tutorial](http://cleancodematters.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/tutorial-gwt-request-factory-part-i/) that illustrates the concept.